# Unable to connect to MySQL installed on another virtual machine or over network

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, laravel, networking

I have several vms instances running in my vm player. Several of them are cent-OS acting as HTTP servers. The HTTP server is/are accessible over network. The HTTP server is on nginx.

Then I have a vm running on cent-OS having MySQL installed. And another vm instance running MS Server 2019 having MySQL Installed. Am using MySQL 8.0.18 on both these machines.

All these machines are on same sub-net and gateway. for example the IP of one of my vm having HTTP server is 192.168.0.133. And the machines with cent-OS having MySQL Server installed is having IP 192.168.0.140 and machine with MS Server 2019 having MySQL server is having IP 192.168.0.141.

Now the issue is am unable to access any of these MySQL servers from the network(LAN) or in other words am unable to access the MySQL server running on either .140 or .141 from the machine .133 meanwhile am able to access the HTTP server across the network.

But if I running MySQL server on the same machine having HTTP server. There occurs no problem whether I use  127.0.0.1 or localhost in my db host configuration

My application is based on a PHP framework known as laravel.

I have disabled firewall from both the above machines. The port 3306 is open on both machines. Am able to ping all machines with each other.

I had tried things like:

skip-networking(commenting out this one or just deleting),
bind-address(IP of the machine running MYSQL server),
grant privileges on an ip or from any IP to users/user,
flush privileges

Even modified iptables.

Am entering db host as the IP of the machine where MySQL is running. 
The error am getting is SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: what are you using for your VM's? Docker?

Comment: VMware Workstation Pro 15

Answer (score 0):

You've nearly done it all right. Setting bind-address to the server's IP however means that you must connect via SSH.

Change the IP to `0.0.0.0` and restart MySQL, and hopefully that should be you all set.